# Invite user by email and set their password

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I have an email address of a user. I’d like to create a user and send them an email with a link to set their password and activate their account. Is this kind of flow support in Keycloak ? I think I can provision user in Keycloak and send executeActionsEmail using UserResource. Is that the right way to do ?

Answer (score -1):

Yes keycloak does support this kind of flow. You can use keycloak admin client for this.
UserResource is the right class for this. You are going in correct direction.

Comment: Can I overiride executeActionsEmail or introduce another method to UserResource ? I need to generate email from my app rather Keycloak.